# react-router-config: You should not use <Switch> outside a <Router>

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have an isomorphic app that uses `react-router-config` v1; I am trying to update to the latest version (`4.4.0-beta.6`). Unfortunately when I try to do so, the server side rendering, previously working well, fails miserably throwing `You should not use <Switch> outside a <Router>`.

```
    const content = renderToString(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <I18nextProvider i18n={ i18n }>
            <StaticRouter location={req.path} context={context}>
                {renderRoutes(Routes)}
            </StaticRouter>
        </I18nextProvider>
    </Provider>
);
```

This appears to be the point of failure; debugging reveals that a `<Switch>` is being instantiated with an `undefined` context, but the context specified in this call is `{}`. I've tried to move `<StaticRouter>` to wrap around the other components but to no avail. I am quite puzzled.

Comment: I'm running into this same issue with react-router-config. Could you post your route config? I'm thinking react-router-config injects a switch depending on whether you need exact matching or not. Just a hunch.

Comment: Nevermind, my problem was that I'd referenced `'react-router-dom'` when requiring `StaticRouter` when its exported from `'react-router'`.

Comment: @keepitreal interesting. I eventually abandoned any hope of upgrading the package!

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Mine used to work with `react-router-dom v4.3.1` but failing with `v5.0.0`. Even after importing StaticRouter from `react-router`, it's giving the same error. I'm not using `react-router-config` though. My setup is simple like in https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/server-rendering.md